# One issue using socket and threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm working with sockets and threads, and I have a problem that I don't understand.
After the accept(), I call thread (using pool created with ThreadPoolExecutor).
The thread called (waitReplay) does receive an object (one command), it creates a new ObjectInputStream, then it does something and at last, it closes the ObjectInputStream.
When I debug I see that closing OjectInputStream (ois.close();) the socket also was closed  even the soc.close() is not invoked. Of course, the next thread doesn't work.

This is the calling code:

```
try {
Socket client = server.accept();    // accept che va in timeout
while (count.getCount()>0)
    pool.execute(new WaitReplay(client, count));

client.close();
accepted = true;
System.out.println("Quorum ragiunto!");

}
```

And the called thread:

```
public class WaitReplay implements Runnable {
    protected Socket soc;
    protected Counter cnt;

    public WaitReplay(Socket soc, Counter cnt) {
        this.soc = soc;
        this.cnt = cnt;
    }

    public void run()  {
        ObjectInputStream   ois;    // input stream
        Message msg;
        InputStream in;

        try {
            in = soc.getInputStream();
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(in);

            msg = (Message) ois.readObject();

            System.out.println("Ricevuto: " + msg.getCmd() + ": Quorum " + cnt.getCount());
            if (msg.getCmd() == Cmnd.OK) {
            cnt.decrement();                            
        }
                ois.close();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("schiatto dentro waitreply");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand that `pool.execute(...)` returns _immediately_?... possibly _before_ the `run()` method of the new `WaitReplay` instance gets called?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.
`pool.execute(...)` is inside on a while instruction that never ends on my testing conditions, so `client.close()` (for the socket), that is outside the while, never execute.
What I see, during debug is that `ois.close()` also close the socket.

Comment: I don't understand the `while(count.getCount()>0)` loop. What does `count.getCount()` do? How long does it take? If it's merely a getter (i.e., if calling `getCount()` does not change anything), then what will prevent the loop from submitting thousands of `WaitReplay` instances to the executor before even one message is received from the client?

Comment: `count.getCount()` return a counter, decremented inside the thread, when a command is received.
The command may be lost or not received. To prevent threads and infinite loop I'm using `ThreadPoolExecutor()` and time-out.

Comment: I think you don't understand `pool.execute(...)`. It will _not_ call the `run()` method of the new `WaitReply` instance. It will only add the new `WaitReply` to a queue. Then, since the counter hasn't changed, the loop will create _another_ `WaitReply` and add it to the queue, and another, and another,... Eventually, a few worker threads will call the `run()` methods of the first several `WaitReply` objects, and they will all simultaneously wait for a message from the client. Meanwhile, the loop will _still_ be adding new `WaitReply`s to the queue, and the count hasn't even changed yet.

Comment: In most applications the life of the ObjectInputStream is exactly the same as the life of socket. Having an ObjectInputStream that is closed before you are ready to close the socket is usually an indication of buggy code/poor design.

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal behavior. Closing a stream will close the underlying stream.

You should not close the ObjectInputStream if you want to keep the SocketInputStream open.

Comment: Ok, Closing a stream will close the stream, so when I close it, in order to release the resource?